# What paramters do I consider to choose SSAS or Powerpoint

Tags: ssas, powerpivot

What paramters do I consider to choose SSAS or Powerpoint?

I am totally new at choosing a BI tool. Where do I start? Is setting up SSAs a doable job for a novice?

Comment: SSAS is used with SQL Server. PowerPoint is used for preparing boring presentations to management.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean SSAS (tabular modeling) vs PowerPivot.  Cathy Dumas has a great post that lists some considerations to take into account when deciding which tool is right for the job...
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cathyk/archive/2011/10/27/when-to-choose-tabular-models-over-powerpivot-models.aspx